# This code isn't working, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction() {

   alert(window[title]);

}
myFunction();
```

I'm expecting to this see the html the title page.

Comment: `ReferenceError: title is not defined`. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Answer (score 5):

First off, `title` doesn't belong to `window`. It belongs to `document`.

Secondly, you've mixed dot notation and array indexer notation, you either need:

```
alert(document['title']);
```

Or:

```
alert(document.title);
```

Unless, of course, you have a variable called `title` that holds the string 'title', in which case it would look something like:

```
var title = 'title';
alert(document[title]);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function myFunction() {

   alert(document.title);

}
```

First off, `window[title]` will make javascript look for the undeclared variable `title`; you probably meant `window['title']`. Second you want `document.title`